# How do I avoid apps script authorisation process?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, authorization

I have a container bound script to a spreadsheet, which I consider the template sheet. I have an option to make a copy of this sheet. If I run any function on the newly created sheet (copy of template), it asks for google authorisation.

Users will be making copy very often, so we don't need this authorisation to be prompted. How do I avoid this authorisation without publishing the script as sheets add-on?

Please help me understand how to avoid this authorisation.

Comment: Won't it just ask them the first time and not again?

Comment: Yes, it is asking only for the first time, but every time when a copy is made.

Comment: Solved this issue by creating a google sheet add-on in G suite Marketplace. This works pretty cool now. Thanks for the responses.

Comment: @KarthickSundar can you guide us to develop google add-on to avoid authorisation prompt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't avoid authorization, cause that would be a security hole. However, there are at least 2 ways to reduce tension:

1) Users won't be asked for authorization, if you only use [simple triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) 
 (like onEdit, onOpen) w/o accessing sensitive scopes.

2) You can add

```
/**
* @OnlyCurrentDoc
*/
```

if script activity is scope to container sheet. This won't remove auth dialog, but will remove "App is unverified" dialog step which might be frightening to new users.