# Best way to share inside my domain a script embedded in a spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, authorization

I have a spreadsheet, with 2 scripts embedded, that monthly is sent to some accounts (teachers) inside my domain. One script reads a form (exam) and write the results in the spreadsheet, the second script transfer the final evaluation (the teacher must add other info to the exam scores) to another public spreadsheet where the people can see the results.
Everything works fine, except that the first run of one of the scripts, asks for Authorization. I'd like to avoid that and I read many articles about Authorize scripts, but I couldn't find the solution.
I don't need to Publish an App, that is far away from my needs and my abilities.
I explored Add-on feature, but in some forums I read that there are limits for the Add-on capabilities and possibly it doesn't work between forms and spreadsheets.

So, is there any option to distribute a script inside my domain and the people are not required to Authorize it?

Comment: Short answer: No.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I avoid apps script authorisation process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61742641/how-do-i-avoid-apps-script-authorisation-process)

Comment: Thank you @IrvinJayG. but I can't use simple triggers because they have same limitation as "They can modify the file they are bound to, but cannot access other files because that would require authorization.".

Answer (score 0):

You can add an installable onEdit trigger from your account, trigger script function if specific cell is updated by the rest of the user.

Comment: Thank you @KevinVaghasiya but, as I said before, triggers have limits and would not work for my case