# how to let google app scripts have a trigger event by app scripts api

Tags: python, google-apps-script

I use the google’s sample and want to let the scripts can log "Hello, world!" every 10 mins
and can see the trigger event on the script website.I don’t want to add the event on the script website with Manual
what should I do ?
If the google has already told I am sorry.
because when I watch the file I can not understand how to do

```
import os.path
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient import errors
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.projects"]

SAMPLE_CODE = """
function helloWorld() {
  console.log("Hello, world!");
}
""".strip()

SAMPLE_MANIFEST = """
{
  "timeZone": "Asia/Taipei",
  "exceptionLogging": "CLOUD"
}
""".strip()


def main():
  creds = None
  if os.path.exists("token.json"):
    creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file("token.json", SCOPES)
  if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
      creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
      flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
          "credentials.json", SCOPES
      )
      creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    # Save the credentials for the next run
    with open("token.json", "w") as token:
      token.write(creds.to_json())

  try:
    service = build("script", "v1", credentials=creds)
    request = {"title": "My Script1"}
    response = service.projects().create(body=request).execute()
    request = {
        "files": [
            {
                "name": "hello", 
                "type": "SERVER_JS", 
                "source": SAMPLE_CODE
            },
            
            {
                "name": "appsscript",
                "type": "JSON",
                "source": SAMPLE_MANIFEST,
            },
        ]
    }
    response = (
        service.projects()
        .updateContent(body=request, scriptId=response["scriptId"])
        .execute()
    )
    print("https://script.google.com/d/" + response["scriptId"] + "/edit")
    

  except errors.HttpError as error:
    # The API encountered a problem.
    print(error.content)


if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Comment: Can you share where you're currently running the script? Also, what's the message that you get when doing so?

Comment: I running this python code on my computer. And It will add a new script to my google app script project. The message on terminal is a link to this new script edit website

Comment: Gotcha. I'm no expert in Python, but from what I know, what you can do with your Google Apps Script code to `log "Hello, world!" every 10 mins` without manually adding the trigger is to use [`newTrigger(functionName)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#newtriggerfunctionname) in combination with [`Manage triggers programmatically`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#manage_triggers_programmatically) in [`Installable Triggers`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable).

Comment: It works!  But now I have a new question. If I want to create this trigger I have to manually run the script on the google edit website. Can I set something to let the script auto run after I run my python code?

Comment: I'm glad to hear that! As for `Can I set something to let the script auto run after I run my python code?` When you create the trigger, you can use [`everyMinutes(n)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#everyMinutes\(Integer\)) to run the function every ten minutes.

Comment: I means when I restart my code. It will create a new script in my google app script project. If I into the edit and  manually run the script the trigger will be created. But I want to run the code and the script will auto run and create the trigger

Comment: I appreciate the explanation. I get what you mean now. You'll need to run the script at least once manually to give authorization, like this [sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOA6I.png), to the generated project from your Python code, and that cannot be avoided. The answer to the post [`How do I avoid apps script authorisation process?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61742641) also explains that `You can't avoid authorization, cause that would be a security hole.`

Comment: Oh that was too bad. Actually I want to do is to control every event in calendar if the event is near. I can get some notice with discord or other communication software. And I have done that in my own account. Now I just want to give other a link then he just put the his calendar_id then the script will auto run in their google account and get the notice as same as mine. It seems like I can put the script into their account but they have to trigger it with theirself

Comment: I'm pretty sure that your users will be able to understand why they need to authorize the script you'll put on their accounts once you explain the situation. If I were in your shoes, I'd also extend my hand by setting up a one-pager that the users can follow in order to easily authorize the script and to get no complaints.